# For landing page A/B testing, how do you recruit from a niche market?

Tags: user-research, validation, ab-testing

I'm currently working with a client that has not launched the full website yet, but is A/B testing ads to drive member acquisition.  The ads direct users to a landing page that collects user e-mails.

We're planning on A/B testing the site copy as well, but we'd like to do it with some user testing prior to making it live.  Since the daily traffic amount is only ~600 visitors, making it live could lower the conversion rate of our already low traffic amount and would not be statistically significant.

We've done some audience segmentation and the target users are affluent, educated, middle aged and mature adults interested in couture products.

I've done recruiting for usability testing and done tons of user research prior, and I'm currently going through the Nielsen Norman Group's paper on recruitment, but I'm not really sure how to recruit this small niche type of user - could I ask for some suggestions from the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try reaching out to local bloggers who write about things related to your product. Send them an email saying that you know that they're an influential voice in your target market. If you contact bloggers with moderate readership (rather than the MOST popular bloggers), they're more likely to have time to read your message and be flattered that you considered them an expert.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are going by NN/g then you [only need to 5 users](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/) (who represent the space) and have them test as many things as you can.

  > Elaborate usability tests are a waste of resources. The best results come from testing no more than 5 users and running as many small tests as you can afford.
- If you have trouble recruiting from your user space, you need to find the closest match to it. Even a similar user group is better than having no testing done. - Scott Klemer, Standford HCI lecturer
- You mentioned that your user base is affluent, educated and middle aged. You can reason with such people. **Ask for their help to improve their experience**. Reach out to their good side and their ego. Send out an email/post it on your website that you need help of people to improve it, maybe you can even mention a thank you note on your site (temporary/permanent).

Answer (score 0):

Are the ads targeted towards new visitors, or in capturing e-mails for existing visitors?

Existing visitors will probably be happy to offer feedback on the site, especially if you lower the resistance to something like an inline comment form, rather than send email + receive survey + fill out survey. (It takes more engineering work, sure, but then you don't just hear back from the people who were so pleased (or so frustrated) that they had to comment.)